# SetThreadExecutionState error

Tags: windows

I entered the following code in a module and call the DoNotSleep() function but it doesn't work. Anyone can help?

```
Enum Execution_State
    ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = &H1
    ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = &H2
    ES_USER_PRESENT = &H4
    ES_CONTINUOUS = &H80000000
End Enum

Declare Sub SetThreadExecutionState Lib "kernel32" (ByRef esFlags As Execution_State)

Public Sub DoNotSleep()
    SetThreadExecutionState(xecution_State.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED Or Execution_State.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED Or Execution_State.ES_CONTINUOUS)
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry forget to add. I using a vb .net application to do this

Comment: Does your program exit after calling SetThreadExecutionState?

Comment: no the application continue to run. I need to stop the user pc from going into sleep mode. any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What is the behavior you are expecting that you are not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

try just

SetThreadExecutionState(Execution_State.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED)

for me on Windows Vista it didn't reset the counter when I also used Execution_State.ES_CONTINUOUS.

The above needs to be called periodically since it resets the counter.